# How do I check if a posts status is set to draft or pending?

Tags: custom-post-types, posts, post-status

I would like to check a posts status, in particular I want to know if a post is set to draft or is privately published.

I have the following code:

```
   if ('draft' !=  get_post_status() || is_user_logged_in()) {
        $this->render();
    }
    else {
        wp_redirect( site_url('404') );
        exit;
    }
```

It checks to see if a posts status is not set to draft or it checks if they are logged in and then renders either the post or redirects to the 404 page.

For some reason privately published posts are visible to non logged in users and I am trying to fix this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To check post with post status `private`, you could run the following:

```
if (get_post_status() == 'private' && is_user_logged_in()) {
     // it's private and user is logged in, do stuff
} elseif (get_post_status() == 'draft') {
     // it's draft, do stuff
} else {
      // it's something else, do stuff
}
```

Or, in your current setup, you can simply only display *published* posts via:

```
if (get_post_status() == 'publish') {
     // it's published, do stuff
     $this->render();
}
```

You can learn more about post statuses via the [codex page](https://codex.wordpress.org/Post_Status).

Comment: Thanks @Christine - used your answer, adapted it slightly and it works!

Comment: Great to hear Neelam; best of luck with your project.

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is with you logic. `||` means if any of the condition is satisfied it'll render, specially if the first condition gets satisfied it'll not check the second one anymore. So your code will be like below-

```
if( !is_user_logged_in() ) {
    return; // or do whatever you want to do if the user isn't logged in.

    // Or these below things 

    // wp_redirect( site_url('404') );
    // exit;
}

if ( 'private' === get_post_status()) {
    // Only render private posts.
    $this->render();
} else {
    wp_redirect( site_url('404') );
    exit;
}
```

So, what we have done above here is, first we checked if the user is logged in or not. If not logged in we are returning it from there. It's no reaching the next if condition. This way you can prevent non-logged in user from seeing this post. In you code some how the first condition gets satisfied and `if` isn't checking the next condition. So non-logged in users are able to see your post. Now in second `if` block we are checking the post status. If the post has `private` status only then it'll be rendered. Other wise it'll be redirected.

> Anyway, some little suggestions, use `!==` rather than `!=` and `===` rather than `==`. These checks types also and makes it strictly checked. See my code, I used these.

Hope this above helps.

Comment: Thanks @the_dramatist for your answer, I went with christine's suggestion and adapted it slightly.